# OAuth SignIn Cordova Firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, inappbrowser

I tried to use OAuth SignIn Cordova Firebase in a hybrid cordova app following the steps from this firebase tutorial:

[Authenticate Using OAuth Providers with Cordova](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova)

But I did not succeed and get the error message below:

> Error: {"code":"auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment","message":"This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. \"location.protocol\" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."}

Comment: are you using signInWithPopup by any chance? you should use signInWithRedirect.

Comment: No, I'm using  signInWihtRedirect method.

Comment: So the SDK will check the URL is file://..., that the app is iOS or android and then listens to deviceready. If any of these checks fail, it will consider the environment not cordova.

Comment: I checked, the protocol is **File** and the `window.cordova` returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the issue was corrected in the latest Firebase JavaScript SDK release (4.1.3)

[Firebase JavaScript SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.1.3)