# Cordova - Best strategy to log in using Facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova

I'm building a Cordova App (no ionic) and I'm facing some issues at picking a way to authenticate via Facebook. These are some option I have tried:

1- Firebase: Couldn't make it work.

2- Ng-cordova-oauth: Works fine and is easy to set up. The only problem is when you connect to facebook the interface looks old.

3- cordova-plugin-facebook4: Couldn't make it work either. But I haven't looked deep for a solution yet.

So these are the approaches I have found so far. What do you recommend? Is there another one better?

Comment: Firebase should be straight forward, what happened when you tried?

Comment: This happened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651423/oauth-signin-cordova-firebase

Comment: That question has an accepted answer that is supposed to solve the problem. So …?